# Code to open a PDF file from within either the assets or raw folder when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

Found quite a few answers on stackoverflow related to this question but I haven't been able to implement any of them successfully. I'm guess it's because people post specific bits of code and I don't know nearly enough Java to modify it to fit my app.

What I'm asking for is the specific lines of code that are needed to open a PDF file saved in the raw folder (was originally assets folder but an answer here said items in the assets folder get compressed and PDF files should go to the raw folder).

From the other answers I've gathered that the file first needs to be copied to internal storage for it to be viewable. That means giving it read and write storage permissions.

A lot of the answers here also show you how to open it within the app (using either libraries or WebView), or open it automatically when the app starts. I don't want either of those behaviors. I want it to open on button click via intents (so it opens with a third party PDF viewer already on the device).

I've created a simple app in Android Studio with a single activity and a single button. It displays a toast when pressed so I know it's properly set up. I have also saved a PDF file in each folder (assets and raw). Please show me how to proceed.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void showPDF (View view) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showPDF"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="135dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="171dp" />
```

Please help. I've been looking for an answer for over 4 days now without avail.

Answer (score 0):

> was originally assets folder but an answer here said items in the assets folder get compressed and PDF files should go to the raw folder

That's not usually a problem.

> From the other answers I've gathered that the file first needs to be copied to internal storage for it to be viewable.

That is the convention nowadays, assuming that by internal storage you mean [what the Android SDK refers to as internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You would then use `FileProvider` to make the PDF available to PDF viewer apps.

> I have also saved a PDF file in each folder (assets and raw)

Use `getAssets().open(...)` on a `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`) to get an `InputStream` on the asset, where `...` is the relative path within `assets/` to the PDF. So, if your PDF is in `assets/doc.pdf`, pass `"doc.pdf"` to `open()`.

Or, use `getResources().openRawResource()` on a `Context` to get an `InputStream` on your raw resource.

Copying the PDF to a local file is then a matter of:

- Creating a `File` object on your desired location (e.g., `new File(getFilesDir(), "doc.pdf")`
- Creating a `FileOutputStream` for that file
- Copying the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`, using standard Java file I/O

You can then configure `FileProvider` (or a subclass) to serve the PDF from wherever you saved it, generate the `Uri`, and craft the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` to open a PDF viewer.

[Here is a complete sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that demonstrates all of this, though I launch the PDF viewer as part of starting the activity, rather than on a button click.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately I'm really new to Java, and can't piece together the bits of code you've given me to make it work. Before this the most I could do is make an image appear on screen while it rotates a bunch of times. If it's not too much trouble could you write down the actual code? I know I'm asking for a bit of a handout here but I've been able to make everything work up until this point using the answers on stackoverflow. I just absolutely can't get this to work and I've been looking for days. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit late but, this code piece's path is raw and you can only reach pdf files with this code.

I hope it helps some

```
 private fun openPDFFile() {
    
            val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT")
            intent.type = "application/pdf"
            startActivityForResult(intent, OPERATION_CHOOSE_PDF)
        }
```